# Searchresults shows filters, category pages does not

Tags: magento-1.7

I found the bugs in my previous question. So, now I have the filters for my custom attribute... But that is only on the search results pages. Not on the category pages.

On the category pages there are no attributes at all, no shop by price or whatever... Just the categories :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities please check below things

1) In admin panel go to catalog >> Attributes >> Manage Attributes >> open your attribute and below image mark part. it's yes or no. 
[image]

2) you may be remove the attributes from the xml file of catalog.

Make sure with above two things.

Comment: all is set: http://i40.tinypic.com/29f9hk1.jpg I maybe have removed something from some .xml file. I get the filters on the searchresults pages. I have checked my local.xml there i have done some testing. but i can only create a extra menu on the side. I have installed a custom vertical menu. After that i got 2 menus (1 new + 1 from theme). I have edited (removed code) to remove the menu and layered navigation. I never cared about the layered navigation on searchresults pages before so i did not remove more code to remove the layered completely. I now have a half layered navigation on search.

Comment: maybe there is something wrong with categories.xml?  I'm lost where and how to check more to fix this. When i use ?supplier=1 in the searchresults pages, i get only the products with that attribute and id. When i do the same on category pages, the breadcrums shops the name of the supplier ID and shows ALL products, not only from supplier 16.

Comment: check your catalog.xml file and catalogsearch.xml file and find the code in that file and put into local.xml file

Comment: in catalog.xml i have this: '<block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>' and in catalogsearch.xml i have this <block type="catalogsearch/layer" name="catalogsearch.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/> when i add 1 extra line i get 2 layers. When i add the catalog.xml code and duplicate it it wont work. When i add <reference name="left"><block type="catalogsearch/layer" name="catalogsearch.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/></reference> to my local.xml i get errors

Comment: please find in local.xml you <remove name="catalog.leftnav"/> in catalog_category_view.

only one prb you miss something in xml file

Comment: found it, removed it and added the block. Nothing. I also replaced the local.xml with the original where layere should work on all pages. Also nothing. I checked the catalog.xml and catalogsearch but they are all original. I am 100% sure have removed code so i get rid of the extra menu. What else can i check?

Comment: i think all is done but last checked if you hide via css ?

Comment: css to hide stuff = adding stuff, i am a destroyer ;) i will now search for "Browse By" in magento original files and check if i get those in my current files. It is just not connecting on the category pages. even the breadcrumbs are broken. crumbs are OK when i use ?supplier=16 behind category url. But result are just all the reults of that category. But when i look at my page meta title. I see the supplier NAME, that is just GREAT, but i need more.

Comment: i have searched for "/layer" i compared my files with original but cannot find missing things. Is there a other way to hide products and show only products from specific attribute value? I have changed my theme to original... still no show on category pages. Where can be the proble? do i need to look at the "/core" folder? o , my.

Comment: no don't change in core files . which magento version you used?

Comment: version: 1.7.0.2

Comment: well, i found something interesting. I have a catalogsearch folder in my theme design folder. That is not a standard folder for my theme. Maybe i can figure out the problem. I have checked all base files, no changes found.

Comment: yes thats grate buddy

Comment: no luck, that catalogsearch folder is from a extension i don't use. I removed the folder and see no changes. What about "shop by price" i'm missing that completely. How is that called? Maybe i turned it of with a button and is it stored in sql?

Comment: you install any external plugin for catalog search then look that extension xml and phtml files

Comment: Don't ask me how, but i see layered navigation on category pages. The only problem now is, when i click the custum attribute i get a error. error log: http://pastebin.com/nnqkrnuJ

Comment: Solved the problem with removing the duplicate layer_view. I now need to figure out how to hide the categories from the layer on category pages. I think the biggest problems are solved for now. Thanks!

Comment: Yes @Maarten Thats Good...

Comment: Please Close this question mark as a right